# Keep the order of the map as in the arrayList before

Tags: java

I am trying to merge line toghether to create data for my programm. Curently the merging part of the `String`s in the `ArrayList`'s *buffer* works well but when I output the content of the `Map` I am getting another of the `String` as they were in the `ArrayList`'s *buffer*.

Is there any way to keep the order of `String`s as they were in the `ArrayList` *buffer*?

**Output:**

```
Nathan Marcus Adler 
[04:43, 05:43, 12:11, 12:41, 19:11, 19:41]
Dukes of Bedford 
[04:56, 05:56, 12:24, 12:54, 19:24, 19:54]
Prince Albert 
[04:48, 05:48, 12:16, 12:46, 19:16, 19:46]
Joseph Addison 
[04:41, 05:41, 12:08, 12:38, 19:08, 19:38]
William Baker 
[04:52, 05:52, 12:20, 12:50, 19:20, 19:50]
```

**The ouput should looks as this:**

```
Joseph Addison 
[04:41, 05:41, 12:08, 12:38, 19:08, 19:38]
Nathan Marcus Adler 
[04:43, 05:43, 12:11, 12:41, 19:11, 19:41]
Prince Albert 
[04:48, 05:48, 12:16, 12:46, 19:16, 19:46]
William Baker 
[04:52, 05:52, 12:20, 12:50, 19:20, 19:50]
Dukes of Bedford 
[04:56, 05:56, 12:24, 12:54, 19:24, 19:54]
```

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();

    buffer.add("Joseph Addison 04:41 05:41");
    buffer.add("Nathan Marcus Adler 04:43 05:43");
    buffer.add("Prince Albert 04:48 05:48");
    buffer.add("William Baker 04:52 05:52");
    buffer.add("Dukes of Bedford 04:56 05:56");

    buffer.add("Joseph Addison 12:08 12:38 ");
    buffer.add("Nathan Marcus Adler 12:11 12:41");
    buffer.add("Prince Albert 12:16 12:46");
    buffer.add("William Baker 12:20 12:50");
    buffer.add("Dukes of Bedford 12:24 12:54");

    buffer.add("Joseph Addison 19:08 19:38");
    buffer.add("Nathan Marcus Adler 19:11 19:41");
    buffer.add("Prince Albert 19:16 19:46");
    buffer.add("William Baker 19:20 19:50");
    buffer.add("Dukes of Bedford 19:24 19:54");

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<PlaceTime> list = new ArrayList<PlaceTime>();

    for (String element : buffer) {
        PlaceTime part = new PlaceTime(element);
        list.add(part);

    }

    for (PlaceTime t : list) {
        if (map.containsKey(t.getPlace())) {
            // If the map already contains an entry for the place, add the
            // times to the array
            map.get(t.getPlace()).addAll(t.getTimes());
        } else {
            // Map does not contain entry for place, create a new entry
            map.put(t.getPlace(), t.getTimes());
        }
    }

    // Print out contents of map
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println("Test");

}
```

**PlaceTime class:**

```
public class PlaceTime {
    StringBuilder place = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> times = new ArrayList<>();;

    public PlaceTime(String placeTime) {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        for (String i:placeTime.split(" ")) {
            try {
                dateFormat.parse(i);
                //No exception, add as time
                times.add(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Exception, add as place name
                place.append(i).append(" ");
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place.toString();
    }

    public List<String> getTimes() {
        return this.times;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between your current output and desired output. Rephrase the question

Comment: Use a `LinkedHashMap`instead, it maintains the insertion order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `TreeMap` to sort natural or customized or `LinkedHashMap` to mantain insertion order:

[`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) for insertion order

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map **(insertion-order)**.

[`Treemap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) for natural or custom sorting

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Instead of [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Comment: `TreeMap` will sort the insertions, `LinkedHashMap` is the key.

Comment: It does not work with TreeMap but it works with `LinkedHashMap`

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` doesn't fallow the iteration order by defenition. It will even change completely when new elements are added so the order is not preserved, use `LinkedHashMap` instead.

It will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map, as desired.

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)